# Linking/using .so file in another

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

i have the following `getmacip.cpp` file with the following snipp code

```
// ...code

#include "test.h"

// ...code   

Test obj;
obj.printDem();

// ...code
```

here is the `test.h` file

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H
class Test
{
    public:
        void printDem();  
};
#endif
```

here is the `test.cpp` file

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printDem()
{
    cout << "deus.ex.machina." << endl;
}
```

i am using java and c++ together via jni. i have gotten the file getmacip.cpp to work together with java and as you can see, i am trying to get the invoke the printDem() method from the getmacip.cpp file. i first compile the getmacip.cpp with the following:

```
g++ -fPIC -o libgetmacip.so -shared -I $JAVA_HOME/include -I $JAVA_HOME/include/linux getmacip.cpp -lc
```

this works fine. however when i do the same with test.cpp and run the program i get the error

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /home/karl/workspace/sslarp/lib/libgetmacip.so: undefined symbol: _ZN4Test8printDemEv
```

i am obviously linking the files wrongly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of the `printDem()` doesn't belong to class `Test`.

Use

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"
using namespace std;

void Test::printDem() {
    cout << "deus.ex.machina." << endl;
}
```

Also you should `link` the method [definition](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_functions.htm) into the shared library, something like this:

```
g++ -fPIC -o libgetmacip.so \
    -shared -I $JAVA_HOME/include -I $JAVA_HOME/include/linux \
        detmacip.cpp test.cpp
```

Also I should mention that raw JNI is a plain-C interface, that's all native calls are performed to functons *declared* as C functions (their *implementation* may use C++, [check this tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jni/j-jni.html). Also there's [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) projects which helps to create required wrappers for C++ automa{g,t}ically.

Comment: Changed the JNI tutorial to a more comprehensive one.

Comment: there we go, thank you! the issue was the g++ compiler command, yours did the trick, i guess you have to compile them together to link them properly

Comment: No, you don't have to. Just _link_ all the parts of the library together. E.g. if you have several `.cpp` files, you may compile them separately, but then you need to do something like `g++ -o <executable-or-library> <required-flags> test1.o test2.o ...

Answer (score 1):

You could check what kind of symbols are here

$ nm -D libgetmacip.so

will produce list of symbols

If you have to demangle C++ names, use c++filt

$ nm -D libgetmacip.so | c++filt

check "man nm" for info how symbols are marked/used

Comment: i got the following: "U" The symbol is undefined.